# arch install mount point question

Tags: arch-linux, mount, partition

Why is the root partition supposed to be installed on /mnt instead of /?  If I am installing arch on its own, separate, unused partition, I do now understand why you would mount the partition on /mnt.  Wouldn't this mean you you could not access the file system on /(anything other than mnt) ??  this has been bugging me for a while and I have not been able to find an sufficient answer.

Comment: Because you are installing into a chroot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are talking about the initial installation. At that time, when you have just booted up, the `/` is the root of the device from which you boot up. After the kernel boots up, it uncompresses a copy of the filesystem (the `initrd`) and mounts that on `/`. Then, the Arch install program asks you to create the needed partitions, and mount them under `/mnt`. After this mount, one does a a `chroot /mnt` that changes the root to the where the OS will be ultimately installed.

Someone can correct me, but I think that instead of `/mnt` one can also say `/abc` and mount in that hierarchy?

Comment: `pacstrap` expects that the partitions will be on `/mnt`; but you point is still valid insofar as it illustrates how the chroot install works.

Comment: This answer and the above comment are exactly what I was looking for.  Installing Ubuntu and other popular distros with the GUI tool, you always mount root partition on /, so I am assuming this shields the user from the details you mentioned in your answer?  So I think this was the source of my confusion.

Comment: Thanks @jasonwryan about the information on `pacstrap` and why I couldn't mount under `/abc` and get away with it :) I haven't looked closely at Ubuntu installs (didn't need to, and Slackware installs are lost in the mists of time), so can't really say how they do it. QQ: Do you mount the root partition on `/` during Ubuntu installation, or you tell it to mount it on `/` post install?

Comment: Yeah during the Ubuntu install you can choose to manually select your partition mounting scheme, and in this tool you can choose where to mount your available filesystems like on "/", "/home" and so on. So id assume since Ubuntu is more mainstream and tuned towards less experienced Linux users that they hide some of those more advanced concepts under the hood of the GUI. Not sure but thats my guess